# Twilio ios Video Call issue

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, videocall

I have created a video call using Twilio JS 2.x Version. And using this in my both mobile app Android & iOS. On Android it is working perfectly.

But on iOS, there is an issue, when users reach the video call page, it's showing preview but as the user clicks on the Join Room button, then his/her video stops and just showing a black screen. But Audio option alone work's fine in ios APP.

Actual thing is we are converting web view in to Mobile sdk using React Native APP. But the twilio logic's has been written using Javascript. Can anyone help on this?

I am using the following logic:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: callInitiate + "?userSTAuthToken=" + token,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      callType: "video",
      subType: "wb-video",
    },
    error: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
      identity = "user_" + userId;
      roomName = meetingId; 
      videoToken = data.token;

      console.log("Joining room '" + roomName + "'...");
      if (previewTracks) {
        connectOptions.tracks = previewTracks;
      }
      // Join the Room with the token from the server and the LocalParticipant's Tracks.
      console.log("Test token : " + data.token);
      Twilio.Video.connect(videoToken, connectOptions).then(
        roomJoined,
        function (error) {
          console.log("Unable to connect to Room: " + error.name);
          TV.Util.DialogIntimation(
            "Notification",
            "Unable to connect to Room " + error.name
          );
          logTwilioerror(10);
          $("#maskDiv").hide();
        }
      );
    },
  });

  function roomJoined(room) {
    window.room = activeRoom = room;
    console.log("Joined as '" + identity + "'");
    addIcons();
    logSessionDetails(videoToken, room.sid, room.localParticipant.sid, room.name);
  
    // Attach LocalParticipant's Tracks, if not already attached.
    var previewContainer = document.getElementById("local-media");
    if (!previewContainer.querySelector("video")) {
      attachTracks(getTracks(room.localParticipant), previewContainer);
    }
  
    // Attach the Tracks of the Room's Participants.
    var remoteMediaContainer = document.getElementById("remote-media");
    room.participants.forEach(function (participant) {
      console.log("Already in Room: '" + participant.identity + "'");
      participantConnected(participant, remoteMediaContainer);
    });
  
    // When a Participant joins the Room, log the event.
    room.on("participantConnected", function (participant) {
      console.log("Joining: '" + participant.identity + "'");
      participantConnected(participant, remoteMediaContainer);
    });
  
    // When a Participant leaves the Room, detach its Tracks.
    room.on("participantDisconnected", function (participant) {
      console.log(
        "RemoteParticipant '" + participant.identity + "' left the room"
      );
      detachParticipantTracks(participant);
      removeName(participant);
    });
  
    // Once the LocalParticipant leaves the room, detach the Tracks of all Participants, including that of the LocalParticipant.
    room.on("disconnected", function () {
      console.log("Left---disconnected");
  
      logVideoActivity(
        "10841",
        "Tutor side disconnected the video Successfully."
      );
  
      if (previewTracks) {
        previewTracks.forEach(function (track) {
          track.stop();
        });
        previewTracks = null;
      }
  
      detachParticipantTracks(room.localParticipant);
      room.participants.forEach(detachParticipantTracks);
      room.participants.forEach(removeName);
      activeRoom = null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Did you try reproducing the issue on a emulator?

Comment: Emulator it is working fine, Facing issues with ios device alone. After joined the room (i.e., Video call ) the screen goes blank.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: // Attach LocalParticipant's Tracks, if not already attached.
    var previewContainer = document.getElementById("local-media");
    if (!previewContainer.querySelector("video")) {
       console.log("Check'" + participant.identity + "'");
      attachTracks(getTracks(room.localParticipant), previewContainer);
    }
  
    var remoteMediaContainer = document.getElementById("remote-media");
    room.participants.forEach(function (participant) {
      console.log("Already in Room: '" + participant.identity + "'");
      participantConnected(participant, remoteMediaContainer);
    });

Comment: @NikolajNielsen,

I'm able to get the first console track, but when the participant's Join the room the screen goes blank only in ios device.

Comment: are you able to test the application on a ios emulator?

Comment: Yes i can test it in ios emulator, video call works fine. Facing issue with ios real device.

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the tracks to preview them and also the code where you call `connect` to join a room? iOS doesn't like you requesting access to more than one camera at a time, even if it is the same camera, and I want to check if that is causing an issue here.

Comment: @philnash, You can see the Piece of Code get the tracks to Preview & to join the Room.

Comment: Hmm, I can’t see anything obvious that might be causing issues with the video. Can you trace through the code to ensure that if you already have preview tracks on the page it’s definitely not trying to re-request them or re-render them.

Comment: Guys can anyone help on this? 

#twilio #ios